# GFS2 File system Support End Date(S) with RHEL6 Server

Tags: gfs

Could anyone let me know, the End Of Life support dates for GFS2 file system for RHEL6 version?
  Raising a track to Redhat is an option for the existing partners to get this information! 
  For me, it is not.  Thanks.

/Franco

Comment: RHEL 6 itself is EOL at the end of November as is anything included therein.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

[This page has RHEL's lifecycle dates and is accessible without a RedHat login.](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#Life_Cycle_Dates)

The same page also contains the definitions of the various terms used.